# Paint removal from electric socket

Tags: paint-removal

I found out some previous tennant of my flat painted the walls with common white wall paint. Unfortunately the bare earth connector (German type F, aka Schuko) on the sockets was painted too. As this is dangerous, I want to remove the paint. Is there a method to remove it by some solvent? I know I could always use sandpaper, but that damages the surface.

Comment: In the US they are inexpensive enough to simply replace. You need to find out what type of paint was used so you can get the correct solvent.

Comment: can you just scrape it off with a screwdriver or small knife, like an xacto? New plates for a rental can be had under 1usd, might be worth it.

Comment: @dandavis I agree that scraping is the way to go. However, I believe the OP is asking about cleaning paint off the ground contact, not the face plate. The [Schuko socket](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/Steckdose.jpg) (Wiki picture link) has exposed ground pins, unlike our US sockets where all contacts are recessed.

Comment: @dandavis New plates are not viable here, because a) there is no paint on them and b) these plates come in a lot of designs, with the only commonality being the collar preventing touching any conductor.

Comment: @FreeMan Right, the problem is paint on the ground pins.

Comment: The cosmetics of the sockets may differ, but behind all that, there is a junction box with an absolutely standard form-factor. You shouldn't have any trouble obtaining sockets dirt cheap. Turn the main circuit breaker off first. (the European style RCD isn't quite sensitive enough to assure human safety).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solvent has the potential to drip and leak onto the line and neutral contacts, potentially causing a short. Of course, you <s>could</s> *should* turn off the breaker to this circuit to kill the power to prevent this danger, and should do so no matter what approach you take to removing the paint.

However, I'd suggest simply using a small utility knife or hobby knife (like an Xacto™ knife) to scrape the paint off first. I've always found that a knife will do a fine job of getting house and/or hobby paint off of hard metal surfaces. Actually, it'll do a pretty good job of getting baked on paint off of a car, too, so I'm pretty sure it will work here.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try the scraping method. Of cause with switching the breaker of first, as I have to remove the face plate first to get access for a blade.